# After upgrading to SonarQube 5.0: MapperParsingException

Tags: sonarqube

I just upgraded to SonarQube 5.0 from 4.2.

SonarQube crashes on start apparently due to a MapperParsingException. I've read the [upgrade notes](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Release+5.0+Upgrade+Notes) but couldn't find a hint on how to solve this. The contents of `opt/sonar/logs/sonar.log` are posted [here](http://pastebin.com/3k5XwrU6).

`uname -a` gives `Linux kuranda 3.11-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.11.8-1 (2013-11-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please stop your instance, remove directory `$SQ_HOME/data/es` and restart the server. This should rebuild the built-in ElasticSearch index from scratch.